# many errors with Warning: include

Tags: php, include-path

I have a script installed on the host that goes well, but I installed the same script on another host, and gives me many errors..

the site where is not working: http://fbswapes.info/

the site where is working: http://swapes.com

I do not understand why these errors if the other host goes well.

in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/languages/lang.php on line 10 I have:

```
include_once($row->path.'.php');
```

in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/header.php on line 884 , I have:

```
mysql_data_seek($result, 0);
```

in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/header.php on line 885 , I have:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, $numass)) {
```

in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/_core/home.php on line 2 , I have:

```
include("../config.php");
```

in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/_core/home.php on line 3 , I have:

```
include_once('../languages/lang.php');
```

in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/footer.php on line 50 , I have:

```
foreach( $total as $sect => $user ){
```

in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/footer.php on line 54 , I have:

```
foreach( $total as $sect => $user ){
```

Please if anyone can help me.. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Have you copied all the include files to the new server? Are they in the same directories relative to the script?

Comment: yes here is all files and all the same

Comment: What is the full pathname where `lang.php` is installed?

Comment: the full code is:

<?
$host = "localhost";
$user = "user_db";
$pass = "pass";
$db = "usr_user";
mysql_select_db($db, mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass)) or die("error!");

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT path FROM language WHERE active = 1");
$row = mysql_fetch_object($sql);
include_once($row->path.'.php');

Comment: I'll ask again, what is the full pathname of the lang.php script?

Comment: The error messages say it's not finding the include files, the rest of the code is irrelevant.

Comment: public_html/Powerful/languages/lang.php  is here in folder language

Comment: Are the folders and files all readable?

Comment: but why in the other host is working and here not? this is strange

Comment: yes all files is readable

Comment: Either you didn't copy everything properly, or there may be a problem with the PHP configuration. The error messages say it expects to find the include files under `/home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/`. Is that where they're installed?

Comment: yes here is installed... but I copied all the files.

Comment: What folder is the main script installed in?

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been wasting lots of time because I misread the errors. It's not saying that it can't find lang.php, it's saying that it can't find a file named `.php` that was included FROM lang.php.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that `$row->path` is empty. There's some problem with your query that tries to get the path information for the active language. Sorry, I have to leave now.

Comment: is this line:  include_once($row->path.'.php'); but is working in other host.

Comment: Maybe the contents of the language database is different.

Comment: I copied all from other host

Answer (score 0):

The file paths seem to be incorrect:

Warning: include(../config.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/xdesign/public_html/Powerful/_core/home.php on line 2

You shouldn't use relative paths, because in some cases there is an ambiguity. Try to rewrite the includes this way:

```
include(__DIR__ . '../config.php');
```

Even in case this doesn't solve the problem, at least the error message will tell where PHP is looking for the files.

Comment: But the error messages must change. They should show absolute paths. What are the new messages?